# CSS menu even spacing and sizing

Tags: javascript, css

I've been wrecking my brain trying to get a navigation menu with properly sized dynamic tabs/buttons working.

So to explain better what I have is the following setup.

```
<div class="main-nav">

<ul>
<li><a href="#">button 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">button 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">button 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">button 4</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Now the main-nav has a fixed width. I'm trying to get the buttons to fill up the full width of the nav. I'm trying to do this preferably without javascript. I've tried a few different things but it doesn't seem to be working cross browser. Specifically ie :(

Has anyone achieved this? or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are your nav li vertical or horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

Specify and percentage width of 25% for each `<li>`. Each `<a>` should have a percentage with of 100%. That should do it.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cxeJk/2/

Comment: Sorry I should add that there is no set amount of buttons. At the moment the tab has 9

Comment: This will work, providing the `<li>`s don't have any borders, margins or padding.

Comment: Oh.. if the number of `<li>`s is not predefined, this won't work. For the styling you can do that within the `<a>` tags, so shouldn't be a problem.